# Set SelectionStart of a WinForms TextBox based on mouse location

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

How can I set the SelectionStart of a WinForms TextBox based on the mouse location? I am extending TextBox and would like to set the carot at the position under the mouse point when the user right-clicks the TextBox (i.e. same behavior as with left-click).

Here's my OnMouseDown override so far:

```
protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right) {
        this.Focus();
        //if we have a range of text selected, leave it
        if (this.SelectionLength == 0) { 
            //set the SelectionStart here based on the mouse location in the MouseEventArgs e         
        }
        //...
    } else
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
}
```

I've investigated using [SetCaretPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648405%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (e.g. `SetCaretPos(e.Location.X, e.Location.Y);`), but couldn't make it work (I see the caret there for a moment, but it is just a flash and does't affect the SelectionStart).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
this.SelectionStart = this.GetCharIndexFromPosition(e.Location);
```